# How to write a model method that references another model?

Tags: django, templates, view, methods, model

I would like to create a model method that will take the "user" (which is a CharField) for
a given review and then return the "quote" associated with that user that is defined as part
of UserProfile.  I am trying to create both the method as well as the template.  The things I've tried so far haven't seemed to work.

I know the best way to do this is probably make the "user" field within
Reviewbackup a ForeignKey to user, but I'd like to know how to be able to do it with a
method so I can learn.

## models.py

```
class Reviewbackup(models.Model):
    review = models.CharField('Review', max_length = 2000)
    user = models.CharField('Username', max_length =  200)
    rating = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, choices=RATING_OPTIONS)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Productbackup)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.review

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    quote = models.CharField('About', max_length =  200, null=True, blank=True)
    website = models.URLField('Personal website/blog', null=True, blank=True)
    facebook = models.URLField('Facebook profile page', max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
    twitter = models.URLField('Twitter profile page', max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
    youtube = models.URLField('YouTube channel page', max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
```

## views.py

```
def view_reviews(request, product_name):
    product = get_object_or_404(Productbackup, url_friendly=product_name)
    product_id = product.id
    #get reviews for the this product
    reviews = Reviewbackup.objects.filter(product_id=product_id).order_by("-created_on")
    return render_to_response('reserve/templates/view_reviews.html', {'reviews':reviews},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

## template

```
{% for review in reviews %} 
{{review.user}}
<br>{{review.user.userprofile.quote}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Have you considered looking it up in `User`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If condition of the problem says "not to use a ForeignKey for user, but use CharField for username" you may add the method to your Reviewbackup model like:

```
def get_user_quote(self):
    return UserProfile.objects.get(user__username=self.user).quote
```

and use it in the template:

```
{{ review.get_user_quote }}
```

But you really should replace your user field to ForeignKey

Comment: Thanks @Dima.  I realize that making it a ForeignKey would be much easier, but I'm struggling with the fact that I have quite a bit of data in my app already.  Can you help me understand what the cons of using a method are as opposed to ForeignKey?

Comment: Reviewbackup database table stores just the user id from the User table. By default it would have an appropriate index, so that joining the tables would work faster.
With ForeignKey you could more easily access the data via orm, like in this case: `{{ review.user.userprofile.quote }}` etc

Comment: If I try to replace CharField with ForeignKey(User), will that have an impact on the data I already have in my app?  Will I have to reload all of it in again because user was previously referring to a string and not an object?

Comment: Of course you will have to write some migrations (or do this manually in sql) so that the user field would point to the right User record in the database.  
You should consider using south migrations if you're not yet

Comment: I am using migrations and this is the error I get when I try to do this: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'sharat' (url is http://localhost:8000/products/glossybox/reviews/).

In the template, the error is pointing to: {{review.user}}

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do when you get the error